# Retrieve user data Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I am wondering how can I retrieve selected user data from Facebook using Facebook SDK C# for Windows Phone 7?

My current code:

```
fbClient = new FacebookClient(App._accessToken);    
fbClient.GetAsync("/me", new Dictionary<string, object> { {"fields", "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture"} , {"access_token", App._accessToken} });
```

What should I do with this code now?

How can I print on the screen my name?

Regards, Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my case. I've solved it with DataContext.

Solution:

**Part of MainPage.cs:**

```
if (App._loggedIn)
            {
                fbClient = new FacebookClient(App._accessToken);

                fbClient.GetCompleted +=
                 (o, arg) =>
                 {
                     if (arg.Error == null)
                     {
                         var result = (IDictionary)arg.GetResultData();

                         // Get user name
                         this.userName = result["name"].ToString();

                         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.DataContext = this);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show(arg.Error.Message);
                     }
                 };

                 fbClient.GetAsync("/me", new Dictionary{{"fields","id,name,first_name,last_name,picture"} , {"access_token", App._accessToken}});
            }
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="text_userName" Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the outpout from fbClient.GetAsync in to a variable, something like

```
JsonResult result = fbClient.GetAsync(
    "/me", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        {"fields", "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture"}, 
        {"access_token", App._accessToken} 
    });
```

then access the retrieved data from result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try your example, I get the error: "The type of namespace JasonResult could not be found.". Do I need to add new dll for this?